# SELECT dentro de um FOR no declare SQL/ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, sqldeveloper

Preciso gerar um excel de uns dados de uma tabela mas preciso fazer para cada empresa minha, para n ter que executar o select mudando o id da empresa pensei em fazer com procedure mas os que tenho e apenas update e insert pensei que a logica seria a mesma mas não esta fluindo. obs nao preciso passar parâmetro.

```
DECLARE

v_nome_empresa VARCHAR2(50);

CURSOR v_empresas IS SELECT  * FROM cf_empresa emp WHERE emp.ID_ADMINISTRACAO = 298;

BEGIN   

  FOR v_empresa IN v_empresas LOOP

  SELECT emp.RAZAO_SOCIAL
        INTO v_nome_empresa
                from EST_PRODUTO_ESTOQUE prodEstoque
                inner join EST_PRODUTO produto on prodEstoque.ID_PRODUTO = produto.ID_PRODUTO
                inner join EST_FORNECEDOR forn on produto.ID_FORNECEDOR = forn.ID_FORNECEDOR 
                inner join CF_EMPRESA emp on prodEstoque.ID_EMPRESA = emp.ID_EMPRESA
                where forn.ID_FORNECEDOR = 99205390 or forn.ID_FORNECEDOR = 106534020 AND v_empresa.ID_EMPRESA = emp.ID_EMPRESA

dbms_output.put_line('Nome empresa '|| v_nome_empresa);
  END LOOP;

END;
```

error retornado :

```
 Relatório de erros -
ORA-06550: linha 19, coluna 2:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: comando SQL não encerrado adequadamente
ORA-06550: linha 11, coluna 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Que modo posso fazer isso?

Comment: Parece estar a faltar um ';' no final do SELECT INTO.

Comment: n foi isso bruno

Comment: Não fala nada mais no erro? Não aponta uma linha nem nada, ou mesmo um código de erro?

Comment: esta no edit novo

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira o select precisa estar dentro de um bloco `BEGIN` `END` acredito que isso tenha causado o erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DECLARE

```
  vf_Arquivo      SYS.UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  vs_caminho      varchar2(25);
  vs_arquivo      varchar2(50);
  vs_linha        varchar(4000);
  CR              CHAR(1) := Chr(13);--CARRIEGE RETURN

BEGIN   
  vs_caminho := '... utl ...';--DIRETORIO PASTA UTL_FILE

  FOR REMP IN (SELECT ID_EMPRESA FROM cf_empresa emp WHERE emp.ID_ADMINISTRACAO = 298)
  LOOP
    --ABRIR ARQUIVO
    vs_arquivo := 'CSV_' || REMP.ID_EMPRESA || '.CSV';
    VF_ARQUIVO := SYS.UTL_FILE.FOPEN(VS_CAMINHO,VS_ARQUIVO,'w');
    --FORS
    FOR RPROD IN (SELECT  EMP.ID_EMPRESA , emp.RAZAO_SOCIAL 
                  from EST_PRODUTO_ESTOQUE prodEstoque
                    inner join EST_PRODUTO produto on prodEstoque.ID_PRODUTO = produto.ID_PRODUTO
                    inner join EST_FORNECEDOR forn on produto.ID_FORNECEDOR = forn.ID_FORNECEDOR 
                    inner join CF_EMPRESA emp on prodEstoque.ID_EMPRESA = emp.ID_EMPRESA
                    where forn.ID_FORNECEDOR = 99205390 or forn.ID_FORNECEDOR = 106534020 AND EMP.ID_EMPRESA = REMP.ID_EMPRESA)
    LOOP
      --MONTA E ESCREVE ESCREVE LINHA
      vs_linha := RPROD.ID_EMPRESA ||';'||RPROD.RAZAO_SOCIA||CR;  
      SYS.UTL_FILE.put_line(vf_arquivo,vs_linha||CR);
    END LOOP;
    --FECHA ARQUIVO
    SYS.UTL_FILE.fclose(vf_arquivo);
  END LOOP;

END;
```

for dentro de for

supõe a existência da [UTL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069) definida , sem chance de testar , mas segue a lógica de coisa que faço para gerar csv´s

este for para sqls muito grandes não seria recomendável

Comment: Desde forum.imasters ate aqui vc vem salvando vlw Motta.

Comment: :) .................